# Как скрыть элемент spinner в bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="spinner">
        <div class="spinner-border text-success" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Использую `bootstrap`. Хочу отображать и скрывать этот спиннер. Как сделать через `js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так тоже

```
  $('#spinner').removeClass('d-none');
  $('#spinner').addClass('d-none');
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var show = document.getElementById('show');
    var hide = document.getElementById('hide');

    show.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var elem = document.getElementById('spinner');
        elem.style.display = "block";
    });
    hide.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var elem = document.getElementById('spinner');
        elem.style.display = "none";
    })
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="spinner">
        <div class="spinner-border text-success" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="show">Показать</button>
<button id="hide">Скрыть</button>
```